# Quick Contact Badge for Unknown number crashes

Tags: android, quickcontactbadge

I am using Quick Contact Badge on Listview. The method `assignContactFromPhone` for unknown number crashes when Quick Contact Badge is clicked. It works fine for the contacts present in the phonebook.

```
quickContactBadge.assignContactFromPhone(number, true);
```

Do let me know on how to set quick contact badge to open activity to add/update contact for unknown number in my call log list

Comment: Solved by treating it as seperate imageView